# how can i import a stack in avl c++

Tags: c++, tree, stack

i have a stack and i want use it in "AVL" tree . (More detail) my "AVL" class have int age and pointers for left,right . but i want add 1 more variable(my stack structure)

```
template<typename T>
class Stack{
public:
           
        Stack(unsigned int size=20)
        ~Stack();
    bool Push(T Item);
    bool Pop(T& Item);
    void WriteAll();
    void Grow(unsigned int size=20);
private:
    T* pDatas;  
    unsigned int Top;
    unsigned int Reserved;
}; 
///////////////////
class NNode  
{  

    public: 
    struct n{
         string name;
    int weight;
    int data;  
    Node *left;  
    Node *right;  
         node * ins(node * tree, int x);
    };
   typedef n node;
};
```

Comment: And what type of items should the stack contain? Do you know in advance or should `NNode` itself be generic?

Comment: Why can't you just add a suitable template instantiation as a member of the node type?

Comment: @Botje items will be char (o ,y ,u )

Comment: @molbdnilo i dont know how can i do

Comment: Okay, so `Stack<char> field_name;`

Comment: Take a step back and learn how to use templates before involving them in your tree.